# How to user Azure ad SSO B2B with "Microsoft.Graph" instead "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[image]

I'm creating an application for my web app but I want to only use Microsoft.Graph instead ActiveDirectory.GraphClient that is possible,if yes then how?

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                };

                options.Scope.Add("openid profile User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Contacts.ReadWrite People.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite");
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer for you is to follow the "[Get Started of ASPNET](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/?platform=ASP.NET)", and then change the logic to suit your requirement.

Do it your by yourself:
Use the Nuget to install the "**Microsoft.Graph**" and then modify the **GraphScopes** in configuration file of project(appsettings.json for NETCore).

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:44334",
    "ClientId": "your client id",
    "ClientSecret": "your secret", // This sample uses a password (secret) to authenticate. Production apps should use a certificate.
    "Scopes": "openid email profile offline_access",
    "GraphResourceId": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    "GraphScopes": "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Send 
  }
```

Modify the configure service code as below:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie();
```

Comment: I'm using asp.net core

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample. A good start point on netcore for you too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21043727)

Comment: @sh0ber Not all answer need to add code. And many net core MVC project can follow the docs of official MVC project docs.

Comment: I got solution and get users basic profile of my organization. Solution: Get Access token using AcquireTokenSilentAsync method. More Details stackoverflow.com/a/52734558/4689622 

Thanks All